# Is the default ASHX handler mapping missing from IIS 7.5 (Windows 7)?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, ashx

I have an application that makes use of the default ASP.NET HTTP handler extension, .ashx.  This no longer works in IIS 7.5.  I get a 404.3 message with instructions to add a handler.

I used the default handler extension specifically to keep things simple and not have to add a mapping within the setup program for my web application.

The new version of IIS seems to have a lot of changes from IIS 6....am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

When you enable ASP.NET, then the mappings are added.  Doh!  I missed this.  It's a little bit buried in Windows 7 when you "turn on" features like IIS.

Comment: DOH, i did the same. Enabled IIS and didn't check that ASP.NET is turned on. Who even needs IIS without ASP.NET >:-|